# The route parameter with '/' is decoded before it is passed to the controller

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to send an http request with `/` symbol. 
For example: `apiAddress/search/18/19`. `18/19` is a search word. 
But I every time get in controller only 18.

I understand that '/' symbol is special and it is parsed as part of the url, so I tried to encode it and send like
`18%2F19` but it doesn't work too.
My search method:

```
[Route("Search/{searchParam}"]
[HttpGet]
public Result Search(string search, ...){
//some code
}
```

Actual result:
Search parameter contains only "18".

Expected result:
Search parameter contains "18/19".

Comment: Have you tried `[Route("Search/{searchParam}/{**anotherSearchParam?}"]`?

Comment: @DavidG I'm sorry, it looks like you were confused by 'anotherSearchParam'.
I want to pass the row '18/19' as one parameter.

Comment: @CodeCaster, look like you are right. Thanks.